# R to Matlab: outer product (%o%) and lower.tri function

Tags: matlab, for-loop

The list (1,2,3,4,5) can have 5*4/2 = 10 combinations. If I want to do pair-wise multiplication, I do this in R as follows:

```
x <- 1:5
mx <- x%o%x
mx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
mx <- mx[lower.tri(mx)]
mx
[1] 2  3  4  5  6  8 10 12 15 20
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply perform a matrix multiplication of an n-by-1 array and a 1-by-n array:

```
out = (1:5)' * (1:5)

out =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     4     6     8    10
     3     6     9    12    15
     4     8    12    16    20
     5    10    15    20    25
```

To get the values below the diagonal, you can do the following

```
idx = tril(true(5),-1);
mx = out(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works, although I'd be happier if I could work out a way to avoid the extra line of code (**UPDATE:** @Jonas has provided a neater solution +1):

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = A' * A;
C = triu(B, 1);
C = sort(C(C ~= 0));

C' =

     2     3     4     5     6     8    10    12    15    20
```